# How to get missing row values to display from another table where count was nonexistent?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Sundays with values Sunday and SundayTimes that come from another table with a where clause to include only for the weekdat sunday. Sunday is the count of the ids for hospital members who logged work in the hours of SundayTimes, which is a list of military times 00:00 to 23:00 that correlate to the count. Since there is no hours logged for 02:00, the table displays as

```
00:00     3
01:00     4
03:00     2
```

How would I account for the missing time so it displays in the format

```
02:00     0
```

in the correct order of the list. I have to be able to account for all possible missing times since the parameters this pulls in can be different from and to dates.

Results for Sunday:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7rhe.png)

Here is what i have so far.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestingTesting123 (Id bigint, WkDay varchar(30), Admittime varchar(5), primary key(Id))
        INSERT INTO #TestingTesting123 (Id, WkDay, Admittime)
            SELECT  r.Id, 
                datename(dw, r.AdmitDate) As WkDay, 
                CASE
                    WHEN r.Admittime = ':'
                        THEN '00:00'
                    ELSE     
                        isnull(LEFT(r.Admittime,2),0) + ':00 '
                    END as AdmitTime
            FROM registrations r
            WHERE r.AdmitDate between @fromdate AND  @todate                    
                AND r.registrationtypeid =  @RegistrationTypeId
            ORDER BY AdmitTime Asc

create table #Sundays (Sunday BIGINT, SundayTimes varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #Sundays (Sunday, SundayTimes)
    SELECT Count(t.Id) As Sunday, 
            t.Admittime as SundayTimes
    FROM #TestingTesting123 t
    WHERE t.WkDay = 'Sunday'
    GROUP BY t.Admittime 

create table #Mondays (Monday bigint, MondayTimes varchar(5))
insert into #Mondays (Monday, MondayTimes)
    Select count(t.Id) As Monday,
            t.Admittime as MondayTimes
    from #TestingTesting123 t
    where t.WkDay = 'Monday'
    group by t.Admittime

create table #Tuesdays (Tuesday bigint, TuesdayTimes varchar(5))
insert into #Tuesdays (Tuesday, TuesdayTimes)
    select count(t.Id) as Tuesday,
            t.Admittime as TuesdayTimes
    from #TestingTesting123 t
    where t.WkDay = 'Tuesday'
    group by t.Admittime

create table #Wednesdays (Wednesday bigint, WednesdayTimes varchar(5))
insert into #Wednesdays (Wednesday, WednesdayTimes)
    select count(t.Id) AS Wednesday,
            t.Admittime as WednesdayTimes           
    from #TestingTesting123 t
    where t.WkDay = 'Wednesday'
    group by t.Admittime

create table #Thursdays (Thursday bigint, ThursdayTimes varchar(5))
insert into #Thursdays (Thursday, ThursdayTimes)
    select count(t.Id) as Thursday,
            t.Admittime as ThursdayTimes
    from #TestingTesting123 t
    where t.WkDay = 'Thursday'
    group by t.Admittime

create table #Fridays (Friday bigint, FridayTimes varchar(5))
insert into #Fridays (Friday, FridayTimes)
    select count(t.Id) As Friday,
            t.Admittime as FridayTimes
    from #TestingTesting123 t
    where t.WkDay = 'Friday'
    group by t.Admittime

create table #Saturdays (Saturday bigint, SaturdayTimes varchar(5))
insert into #Saturdays (Saturday, SaturdayTimes)
    select count(t.Id) as Saturday,
            t.Admittime as SaturdayTimes
    from #TestingTesting123 t
    where t.WkDay = 'Saturday'
    group by t.Admittime



declare @FinalResults table(AdmitTime varchar(5), Sunday bigint, Monday bigint, Tuesday bigint, Wednesday bigint, Thursday bigint, Friday bigint, Saturday bigint)
insert into @FinalResults (AdmitTime, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday)
    select su.SundayTimes as AdmitTime,
            su.Sunday as Sunday,
            m.Monday as Monday,
            t.Tuesday as Tuesday,
            w.Wednesday as Wednesday,
            th.Thursday as Thursday,
            f.Friday as Friday,
            s.Saturday as Saturday
    from #Sundays su
    inner join #Mondays m on m.MondayTimes = su.SundayTimes
    inner join #Tuesdays t on t.TuesdayTimes = su.SundayTimes
    inner join #Wednesdays w on w.WednesdayTimes = su.SundayTimes
    inner join #Thursdays th on th.ThursdayTimes = su.SundayTimes
    inner join #Fridays f on f.FridayTimes = su.SundayTimes
    inner join #Saturdays s on s.SaturdayTimes = su.SundayTimes

select fr.AdmitTime, 
        fr.Sunday, 
        fr.Monday, 
        fr.Tuesday, 
        fr.Wednesday, 
        fr.Thursday,
        fr.Friday,
        fr.Saturday
from @FinalResults fr
```

drop table #TestingTesting123
drop table #Sundays
drop table #Mondays
drop table #Tuesdays
drop table #Wednesdays
drop table #Thursdays
drop table #Fridays
drop table #Saturdays

Comment: What SQL Server version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Before your last query, you could add this step :

```
DECLARE @i INT;
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(5);
SET @i=0;
WHILE @i < 24
BEGIN
    SET @time = RIGHT('00'+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+':00'
    INSERT INTO @Sundays
    SELECT 0, @time
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

Sorry if there is a mistake, I couldn't test before posting.

Explication : Just in case, one hour is missing we add all hours with 0 as count.

**NEW ANSWER :**

```
create table #empty_hours (Days BIGINT, Times varchar(5))
DECLARE @i INT;
DECLARE @time VARCHAR(5);
SET @i=0;
WHILE @i < 24
BEGIN
  SET @time = RIGHT('00'+CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+':00'
  INSERT INTO #empty_hours
  SELECT 0, @time
  SET @i = @i + 1;
END

INSERT INTO #Sundays SELECT * from #empty_hours ;
INSERT INTO #Mondays SELECT * from #empty_hours ;
INSERT INTO #Tuesdays SELECT * from #empty_hours ;
INSERT INTO #Wednesdays SELECT * from #empty_hours ;
INSERT INTO #Thursdays SELECT * from #empty_hours ;
INSERT INTO #Fridays SELECT * from #empty_hours ;
INSERT INTO #Saturdays SELECT * from #empty_hours ;
```

**New explanation :**

We create an #empty_hours temporary table ; We fill it with all hours with 0 as account (no incidence for the result). Then you insert those 'empty' values in all your tables in case some hours are missing.

Comment: I'm getting the red incorrect syntax line underneath @time, '00', @i, and 2 for only those values in the line after BEGIN.

Comment: I forgot to add 'SET'. I have just edited my post. Hope it works.

Comment: That works but the only problem is that it made my group by clause in those tables obsolete, so the times are repeating over and over.

Comment: Can you show us the output of this query please : SELECT * FROM #Sundays;

Comment: Can't see anything.

Comment: I can't put up a picture, but when the results from final results display (bc that is where the table is missing times) but there are 8 columns with the headers in this order AdmitTime, Sunday, Monday --> Saturday. In the AdmitTime column, all the times 00:00 --> 23:00 display except 02:00. In the Sunday column, the first few values are 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5 etc. This is the same for the rest of the weekday columns. Because in my final results table I joined them by AdmitTimes and Sunday never had the 02:00 admit time column, 02:00 is being left of as part of the data in the AdmitTimes column.

Comment: Ok but first I would like to see 'SELECT * FROM #Sundays; ' . Could you edit your question and show the contents of this table ?

Comment: Actually the picture is in there now.

Comment: Did you INSERT INTO #Sundays SELECT * from #empty_hours ; ? You must be sure to insert the content of #empty_hours into each tables (sundays, mondays, etc ...).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is what you need. You don't need to use separate tables for each day.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestingTesting123 (Id bigint, WkDay varchar(30), Admittime varchar(5), primary key(Id))
    INSERT INTO #TestingTesting123 (Id, WkDay, Admittime)
        SELECT  r.Id, 
            datename(dw, r.AdmitDate) As WkDay, 
            CASE
                WHEN r.Admittime = ':'
                    THEN '00:00'
                ELSE     
                    isnull(LEFT(r.Admittime,2),0) + ':00 '
                END as AdmitTime
        FROM registrations r
        WHERE r.AdmitDate between @fromdate AND  @todate                    
            AND r.registrationtypeid =  @RegistrationTypeId
        ORDER BY AdmitTime Asc

-- table with all hours in day
declare @Hours table
(
    T_Hour varchar(5)
)

declare @i smallint
set @i = 0
while @i < 24
begin
    insert into @Hours
    select right('00' + cast(@i as varchar), 2) + ':00'

    set @i = @i + 1
end

-- result query
select 
    T_Hour,
    ISNULL(SUM(case when WkDay = 'Sunday' then CountValue else 0 end), 0) as Sunday,
    ISNULL(SUM(case when WkDay = 'Monday' then CountValue else 0 end), 0) as Monday,
    ISNULL(SUM(case when WkDay = 'Tuesday' then CountValue else 0 end), 0) as Tuesday,
    ISNULL(SUM(case when WkDay = 'Wednesday' then CountValue else 0 end), 0) as Wednesday,
    ISNULL(SUM(case when WkDay = 'Thursday' then CountValue else 0 end), 0) as Thursday,
    ISNULL(SUM(case when WkDay = 'Friday' then CountValue else 0 end), 0) as Friday,
    ISNULL(SUM(case when WkDay = 'Saturday' then CountValue else 0 end), 0) as Saturday
from @Hours
    left outer join 
    (
        select WkDay, Admittime, count(Id) as CountValue                
        from #TestingTesting123
        group by WkDay, Admittime
    ) T 
    on T_Hour = Admittime  
group by T_Hour
```

Comment: So I would be inserting into table testing Sunday all hours of the day, Monday all hours of the day, Tuesday all hours of day and continue that through Saturday?

Comment: I'm getting the error that there is already a table with that name (testingtesting123). Also how would I be getting the r.Id value from table registrations if I am creating a new table testingtesing123 that has no reference to table registrations at all.

Comment: Replace your own creation and filling testingtesting123 in my example.